# How to format string to date

Tags: php, laravel

I trying to format string to date. String looks like that: 20200219 and I want to format it like 2020-02-19. Can some help me with this?

Comment: Is `20200219` just a string or is it a date object in php?

Comment: Hello. It appears that the first 4 chars are the year. The next 2 are the month. And the next 2 are the day. You will need to write some code to parse this into the date you want. You could take a look into `substr()` a built-in string function in PHP to get started.

Comment: Despite solutions below that use PHP's `date()` function, you have to be careful if you actually want a date respective of the current locale and timezone, or you just want a date as it was *originally encoded* which actually looks like your goal. So if you for example as you mentioned `20200219` then your best bet is the `substr()` function. Fortunately this data format looks fixed width.

Comment: It was a good question OP. You *didnt* have a code attempt which was not cool But I didn't want you steered the wrong way on this particular problem. Hopefully in near future you can share the coding talents you have by actual source code. Im one of those guys that like learning at how other ppl do things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You have multiple options:**

Use strtotime() on your first date then date('Y-m-d') to convert it back:

```
$changed_date = "20200219";

echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime($changed_date ) );

$time = strtotime('03/05/2020');

$newformat = date('Y-m-d',$time);

echo $newformat;
// 2020-03-05
```

You need to be careful with m/d/Y and m-d-Y formats. PHP considers / to mean m/d/Y and - to mean d-m-Y. I would explicitly describe the input format in this case:

```
$ymd = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', '03/05/2020')->format('Y-m-d');
```

Another Option:

```
$d = new DateTime('03/05/2020');

$timestamp = $d->getTimestamp(); // Unix timestamp
$formatted_date = $d->format('Y-m-d'); // 2020-03-05
```

Comment: OP specifically mentions that he/she is starting out with a data format of like form `20200219` where the year (4), month (2), day (2) where the parenthesis denote char lengths are concatenated with no sentinel.

Comment: made the change mate!

Comment: This solution however can still result in a "day" change, and possibly a "month" or "year" if the *recorded* date differs from the *timezone* in which the `date()` function is called. `date()` uses the current time which is not present in the source data. Imagine if this were a "receipt" or something else of significant historical value? It's simpy *wrong* to use the *date()* function for OP's question.

Comment: I have not checked it but it may cause issues in the conditions you have mentioned!

Comment: Please use `DateTime` like in this answer, not strtotime. It gives you more control over the input and how it is parsed, finer control over timezones etc. strtotime is just a black box without any control.

Comment: We can use it but there may be issues

Comment: But there may be issues...? Consider the OP's question as a formatting problem, not a *date changing potental solution*. I guess I will be posting the correct answer shortly.

Comment: Sure go ahead with your solution

Answer (score 1):

> you can do like that

```
$s = '20200219';
$date = strtotime($s);
echo date('Y-m-d', $date);
```

Answer (score 0):

if it's a string you could do like this:

```
$date=date_create("20200219");
return date_format($date,"Y-m-d");
```

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:-

```
$var = "20200219";
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime($var) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try php way:

```
date("Y-m-d", strtotime("20200219") );
```